# How should I configure the a connection to MS Azure cloud database using pyodbc?

Tags: python, azure, azure-sql-database, pyodbc

I'm setting up a python script to connect to an instance of the azure cloud database, and seeing a difference in the connection when I use IDLE vs when I try to execute the connection from a script.  For example, when I do the following in IDLE:

```
>>> import pyodbc
>>> conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=<my.database.host.info>,1433', user='<my_username@mydatabase', password='password', database='database')
```

I'm able connect successfully and execute a basic query against one of the tables in the database.

However when I use the same connection string (copied from the IDLE console) in a script, I get the following error:

```
pyodbc.Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Comment: Are you sure your IDLE and script interpreter are the same python? Is it possible that your IDLE is python 2, while your script interpreter is python 3?

Comment: If @JackZeng's suggestion doesn't work, you may also want to check your Python path from the environment you're invoking the script versus in the IDLE environment. Are you using a virtualenv in either?

Comment: Yes, I checked the sys.version from both IDLE and my script. I'm running both locally.

Comment: In which situation and environment, you failed to process this script?

Comment: this is very interesting, do you use the Microsoft ODBC Driver with pyodbc or some other ODBC Driver?

Comment: I'm using the Microsoft ODBC Driver with pyodbc. I'm on Windows 7.

Comment: I mean, how do you run your script? `python script.py`? Or you run in any python framework?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the issue is raised because the 32/64 bit version of python environment and odbc driver are mismatched.

You may check the python version and odbc driver version you used to run the script. You have to manage to change both of them need to be 32-bit (or both 64-bit) in order for this to work.

You can get the specified version of pyodbc extension from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyodbc.